# OOP: two very similar methods, but different types of data --howto optimise?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods

I'm trying to optimise some code. Specifically, I have two methods that are very similar in terms of what they do. The operations they perform are the same, the difference is that one concatenates strings, and the other appends these strings into a list. The only parts of the methods that are different are the instances that involve string or list-specific methods/operations.

example:

```
    class Some_Class:
        def __init__(self, num): 
            self.num = num 

        def some_function(self): 
            collector = ''
            for x in range(self.num):
                #do something
                collector+= #the something
            return collector

        def some_function(self): 
            collector = []
            for x in range(self.num):
                #do something
                collector.append(#the result of something)
            return collector
```

What would be the best way of optimising the code? A simple

```
    if type(data) == str:
        #do something
    else:
        #assume it's a list, and act accordingly
```

...results in unsightly, hard to heard code, as I would have to write this in multiple places. Recommendations?

Comment: A downvote with no explanation? Real classy.

Comment: you have called your methods the same name, so the interpreter will only find one.

Comment: on a side-not, you could use the `list` method, and when you know it is on a string-value you want concatentated, use `''.join(list_result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting what you are wanting, but here are some suggestions anyway.

If your two methods as you say are similar, essentially doing the same thing, but producing a differently formatting response, what you could do is something like the following to consolidate duplicated code into a single private function of the class:

```
class Some_Class:
    def __init__(self, num): 
        self.num = num 

    # obviously these two `some_function`s wouldn't have the same name?
    def some_function(self): 
        collector = ''
        for x in range(self.num):
            result = self._do_something(<some args>)
            collector+= result
        return collector

    def some_function(self): 
        collector = []
        for x in range(self.num):
            result = self._do_something(<some args>)
            collector.append(result)
        return collector

    def _do_something(self, <some args>):
        # common function containing all the repeated functionality
        # between the other two functions

        # do something
```

If you must have everything in a single function, then your if/else example is probably still a good way to go. Perhaps using a `bool` variable instead of calling `type` everytime would be neater though.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be some snazy way of solving my problem, but thanks for the input! :)